# Index and length must refer to a location within the string when I try to add an extra digit?

Tags: c#

Hello so I have a program that generates a Key when you fill in some info in some text boxes. When ever I generate a key that adds an extra 1 or 0 it tells me Index and length must refer to a location within the string, this is the code:

```
public virtual string GenerateKey(string BreedPub)
        {
                return GenerateKey() + BreedPub.Substring(0, 3);
        }
```

and I think it's conflicting with this:

```
public override string GenerateKey(string BreedPub)
        {
            string key = null;
            if (Pedigree == "1")
            {
                key = GenerateKey() + BreedPub.Substring(0, 3) + "1";
            }
            else
            {
                key = GenerateKey() + BreedPub.Substring(0, 3) + "0";
            }
            return key;
```

now i've tried to change the substring to (0,4) or doing this:

```
public virtual string GenerateKey(string BreedPub)
        {
            if (Pedigree == "1")
            {
                return GenerateKey() + BreedPub.Substring(0, 3) + "1";
            }
            else if (Pedigree == "0")
            {
                return GenerateKey() + BreedPub.Substring(0, 3) + "0";
            }
            else
            {
                return GenerateKey() + BreedPub.Substring(0, 3);
            }
        }
```

but it still gives me the same error message, what could I be doing wrong?

Comment: I am lost between the GenerateKey calls, but as simple as that. What is the value of BreedPub on the first call to this code?

Comment: How do you know `BreedPub` has at least 3 characters in it?

Comment: The error is telling you exactly what the problem is: BreedPub is less than 3 chars long.

Comment: This is embarassing but I forgot to add a dog.BreedPub = cmb_Breed.Text somewhere, anyways thanks for the help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

BreedPub.Substring(0, 3) is probably throwing the exception because your BreedPub argument is too short.  You should add some range checking to make sure the parameter is at least 3 characters long.

Comment: This is embarassing but I forgot to add a dog.BreedPub = cmb_Breed.Text somewhere, anyways thanks for the help